# News webpart with comments

Tags: comments

I'm willing to add a News app that would allow users to comment it when they click on it. But i don't know where to begin or what do i have to search for to get this. I've read somwhere you need an annoucment list for that. But i don't where the user can comment on this. Can you help me please? I'm not search for newsfeed thing tho

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your news articles are Article Pages in a Pages library. SharePoint has a default column, ID that you can use to uniquely identify each item in the library.

Build a custom list with the columns required for your Comment system, and add an extra column, ArticleID. Each comment item will be 'related' to an existing article's ID. Each item should be written to the list with the relevant article's ID value in the ArticleID column of Comments list.

That's how simple the logic can be: next you need to build you front-end, which will allow the comment to be input and write the relevant value in the ArticleID field - your users shouldn't be required to worry about inputting the ID

Depending on your approach to development of the front-end, depends how you'll write to and read from the lists.

If you have any experience with JavaScript you could make use of SPServices for this; you can post items to the Comments list with ajax and update the view of comments on the page.

I hope it helpss